# Salesforce support case - mandatory field disabled

Tags: api, salesforce-support

My organization recently reached a 24hr API limit. While I am not sure how this happened I am trying to contact support to temporarily increase the limit at [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder&topic=Development&category=API_or_Integration&question=Increase_the_Bulk_API_limit&logACase) (found in the Help & Training Portal).

However the "description" field is unselectable but appears to be mandatory - I cannot enter text but a red "required" appears below.

Is there any workaround to this? Is there a better way to contact support?

Comment: the link you shared is unaccessible

Comment: @glls thank you for the heads up, i will update with a screenshot